# Bundling with application cache in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I am working with an MVC project. And I use the application cache to store my whole page to the cache so that the application is still available even offline.

This is my Offline Controller

```
   public class OfflineController : Controller
   {
    //
    // GET: /Offline/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var manifestResult = new ManifestResult("1.0")
        {
            CacheResources = new List<string>() 
             {
                Url.Action("Index", "Home"),
                BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css", true),
                BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/modernizr", true),
                BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jquery",true),
                BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jqueryui", true),
                BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jqueryval",true),
                BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/modernizr",true),
                BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css",true),
                BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/themes/base/css")
             },
            NetworkResources = new string[] { "*" },
            FallbackResources = { { "Images/offline.jpg", "Images/offline.jpg" } } 
        };
        return manifestResult;
    }


}
```

My Home Controller is this

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {  
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

This is my class that generate the manifest file

```
 public class ManifestResult : FileResult
{
    public ManifestResult(string version)
        : base("text/cache-manifest")
    {
        Version = version;
        CacheResources = new List<string>();
        NetworkResources = new List<string>();
        FallbackResources = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> CacheResources { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> NetworkResources { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> FallbackResources { get; set; }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        WriteManifestHeader(response);
        WriteCacheResources(response);
        WriteNetwork(response);
        WriteFallback(response);
    }

    private void WriteManifestHeader(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        response.Output.WriteLine("CACHE MANIFEST");
        response.Output.WriteLine("#V" + Version ?? string.Empty);
    }
    private void WriteCacheResources(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        response.Output.WriteLine("CACHE:");
        foreach (var cacheResource in CacheResources)
            response.Output.WriteLine(cacheResource);
    }
    private void WriteNetwork(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        response.Output.WriteLine();
        response.Output.WriteLine("NETWORK:");
        foreach (var networkResource in NetworkResources)
            response.Output.WriteLine(networkResource);
    }
    private void WriteFallback(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        response.Output.WriteLine();
        response.Output.WriteLine("FALLBACK:");
        foreach (var fallbackResource in FallbackResources)
            response.Output.WriteLine(fallbackResource.Key + " " + fallbackResource.Value);
    }

}
```

Here is the error that I encounter
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer, for those of you that just landed here, this is the implementation/article  being referenced:

http://www.infoq.com/articles/Offline-Web-Apps

I was able to get this working just fine. One difference between your implementation and mine is that you are listing your manifest as such in the HTML tag:

```
<html manifest="/Offline">
```

.. or so I'm guessing.. you didn't post your HTML. I am not sure that HTML tag will be properly interpreted. Here is what I am using and works fine:

```
<html manifest="/Mobile/Manifest">
```

My guess is that "Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (-1)" is the equivalent of a 404.

Hope this helps... I see it's been quite a while since you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue of the css and script resources not loading in offline mode, when using the same [infoq blog post](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Offline-Web-Apps) as an example. I resolved the issue by adding the script and css resources using `Scripts.Url` instead of `BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl`.

My solution is based on a [blog post](http://technicalitiesblog.blogspot.com/2014/05/html5-appcache-with-mvc-bundles.html) by [Eoin Clayton](http://www.eoinclayton.com/).

Using the Offline controller code you posted as a base, it may work if you modify it to look as follows:

```
    public class OfflineController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Offline/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var manifestResult = new ManifestResult("1.0")
            {
                CacheResources = new List<string>() 
                {
                    Url.Action("Index", "Home"),
                    Scripts.Url("~/bundles/jquery").ToString(),
                    Scripts.Url("~/bundles/modernizr").ToString(),
                    Scripts.Url("~/bundles/bootstrap").ToString(),
                    Scripts.Url("~/Content/css").ToString()
                },
                NetworkResources = new string[] { "*" },
                FallbackResources = { { "Images/offline.jpg", "Images/offline.jpg" } }
            };
            return manifestResult;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.